# Error while saving Application settings: "There was a problem saving your changes. Please try again later."

Tags: facebook, dashboard

call-for-help: we are keep getting the illustrated error after hitting "save changes" in the application settings dashboard ... the changes are saved though ... any link where we can report our app issue?

http://awesomescreenshot.com/046la8j4f

Comment: I'm seeing the same problem. changes are saved, but NOT the namespace change, and our app is not working anymore

Answer (score 0):

This is not a problem with your app.. 
This happens sometimes because your app server might have taken a longer time to update on FB servers and the connection timed out...
Nothing to worry about you an try again

Comment: Thanks for the comment Mahima. The changes *are* saved as mentioned before ... the problem is that in the last 3 days I keep getting the error ...

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and solved it by checking all the icons and screenshots. I made sure that they all was in the same format (.png) and then it worked!

I guess the issue, for me, is that i used different formats.